# Alert ao entrar em condição no Controller Asp Net MVC

Tags: .net, mvc, asp

Boa noite, tentei procurar em outros posts e não encontrei a resposta.
Tenho um Controller no meu projeto Asp Net MVC que tem essa condição:

```
  if (resultado == null)
        {

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuário ou senha inválidos");
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Nav");

        }
        else
        {

            if (produto != null)
            {
                carrinho.AdicionarItem(prod, quantidade);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Nav");
        }
    }
```

tentei de diversas formas colocar uma mensagem para caso a condição fique no IF, para exibir uma mensagem de alerta para o usuário, mas não consigo. Cheguei a tentar com TempData mas exibiu escrito apenas, queria um Alert ou Pop Up de alerta. Tentei por ultimo com ModelState e colocando o  @Html.ValidationSummary() na view, mas tambem não exibiu o Pop-Up. Tentei com FlashMessage  e não consegui tambem. Alguem pode me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Você pode melhorar sua questão adicionando mais detalhes. Assim possibilita que outros possam de auxiliar com mais precisão.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode checar o modelstate ou qualquer outra coisa que quiser na **view** e chamar o alert do javascript

```
@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ModelState.isValid)) {
    <script>alert("Mensagem de erro");</script>
}
```